# Getting the manifest version of a jar file using unzip in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the implementation version of a jar file using the unzip command in a powershell script. I got few results but not all of them. If i run the same command from the powershell command it works but not from the script.

**This is the code that I use**

```
@{n='v';Expression={unzip -q -c $_.fullname META-INF/MANIFEST.MF |findstr Implementation-Version}}
```

For example a file called `rt.jar` , I am able to run it directly on the command prompt  but it comes empty in the script using the above in the as part of the `Get-ChildItem` and `Select-Object`

**From the command prompt:**

```
PS C:\PC\Libaudit> unzip -q -c "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\lib\rt.jar" META-INF/MANIFEST.MF |findstr Implementation-Version
```

Implementation-Version: 1.8.0_201

**Section of the code**

```
  ForEach ($Loc in $LocStr){
  Get-ChildItem -Path $Loc -Include $Extensions1 -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object @{Name='f'; Expression={$_.name}},@{Name="p"; Expression={$_.fullname}},@{Name='h'; Expression={$System}},@{Name='a'; Expression={$values}},@{Name="s";Expression={Get-FileHash $_.fullname -Algorithm "SHA256"}},@{n='v';Expression={unzip -q -c $_.fullname META-INF/MANIFEST.MF |findstr Implementation-Version}},@{Name='Live'; Expression={$live}}      
                    }
```

Comment: should this `$_.fullname META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` be just hanging out like that? it looks like you are attempting to add a `dir\file.ext` to the `.FullName`. is the `.FullName` a dir? shouldn't there be a `\` between it and the `META-*` stuff? shouldn't there be quotes around that path?

Comment: Good point.  I will update and try that

Comment: good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).